# Tile title on Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I migrated my app from WP8.0 to **WP8.1 Silverlight**. Now the tiles won't show the title/app name anymore.

The Package.appxmanifest (part for tiles) currently looks as follows

```
  <m3:VisualElements DisplayName="Time Stamp" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Startscreen-Medium-Tile.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Applicaton-Icon.png" Description="Time Stamp work time tracker" ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="transparent">
    <m3:DefaultTile ShortName="Time Stamp" Square71x71Logo="Assets\Startscreen-Small-Tile.png" Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Startscreen-Wide-Tile.png">
      <m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
        <m3:ShowOn Tile="square150x150Logo"></m3:ShowOn>
        <m3:ShowOn Tile="wide310x150Logo"></m3:ShowOn>
      </m3:ShowNameOnTiles>
    </m3:DefaultTile>
    <m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen\SplashScreenImage.scale-240.jpg" />
  </m3:VisualElements>
```

I've been searching the docs for some time now and couldn't figure out what's missing. What caught my eye is the following Note which belongs to the description for the *ShortName* attribute of *DefaultTile* (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn391672.aspx)

```
Note As of Windows 8.1, this property is ignored and the display name 
declared in the manifest is used in its place.
```

Although it mentions Windows instead of Windows Phone I was wondering what manifest it refers too. Maybe the docs are not 100% correct here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens sometimes, right after asking the question I figured out what is causing the issue. It seems like the project just had to be rebuild completely in order for the the tile titles to show up properly. No wonder I couldn't find any info on this in the docs as it should be clear to do that whenever the manifest changes.